# Marketing Cloud - importing file (csv) to data extension errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, csv

I have a few issues moving data from a csv in an external FTP to a data extension using the file import activity.

CSV files without data (but with headers and proper associated fields in the DE) error out when being run.

CSV files with data do not error out, but nothing is being populated in the actual DE...

Is there a reason empty CSV (besides the header) would error out? Is there a way around that? Also, is there some reason data would not be populating correctly for the imports that did not error out but have data?

Comment: Could you post the message from the logger?